# How to properly display icons to the left of html audio player?

Tags: html, css, icons, inline

I'm trying to get my icons to appear to the left of my audio player (at the end). The inline-block isn't working. Not even in JSfiddle. Any suggestions?

I appreciate it!

The current code/css I have (JSFiddle):

http://jsfiddle.net/qMdfC/620/

Css

```
.socials-paypal i {

    width: 37px;
    height: 37px;
    float:left; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #1b1b1b;
    color: #dbdbdb;
    line-height: 37px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

source

```
<body>
<div>
    <h1 class="text-center">'Zel</h1><br>   
    <audio src="audioplayer/audio/letmeknow.mp3" controls> 
        Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </audio>

<div class="socials-paypal">
    <a href="facebook.com/TheRealZellyZel"><i class="fa fa-paypal"></i></a>
    <a href="Twitter.com/TheRealZellyZel"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
    <a href="Twitter.com/TheRealZellyZel"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
<div class="footer-socials"></div>
```

Comment: move `socials-paypal` div above `audio`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `display: inline-block` to your class `socials-paypal` and re-order your DOM. Like this:

```css
audio {
      display: inline-block;
    }
    .socials-paypal i {
      width: 37px;
      height: 37px;
      float: left;
      display: inline-block
      -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
      border-radius: 50%;
      background-color: #1b1b1b;
      color: #dbdbdb;
      line-height: 37px;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 14px;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
      -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
      -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
      -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
      transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    }
    .socials-paypal {
      display: inline-block;
    }
```

```html
<div>
            <h1 class="text-center">'Zel</h1>
            <br>
            <div class="socials-paypal">
              <a href="facebook.com/TheRealZellyZel"><i class="fa fa-paypal"></i></a>
              <a href="Twitter.com/TheRealZellyZel"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
              <a href="Twitter.com/TheRealZellyZel"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
              <div class="footer-socials"></div>
            </div>
            <audio src="audioplayer/audio/letmeknow.mp3" controls>
              Your browser does not support the audio element.
            </audio>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can move the `<div class=socials-paypal">` with all its content before the `<audio src="audioplayer/audio/letmeknow.mp3" controls>` you will end up with what you were looking for I think.

I provided a jsfiddle with the update.
http://jsfiddle.net/qMdfC/622/ (as a sidenote, you had missed a ";" at the end of your inline-block in the jsfiddle that you linked in your original post.)

Answer (score 0):

It was the problem of your ordering of div and audio tags.
Just change it to like this:

```css
.socials-paypal i {
  width: 37px;
  height: 37px;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #1b1b1b;
  color: #dbdbdb;
  line-height: 37px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <h1 class="text-center">'Zel</h1>
    <br>
    <div class="socials-paypal">
      <a href="facebook.com/TheRealZellyZel"><i class="fa fa-paypal"></i></a>
      <a href="Twitter.com/TheRealZellyZel"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
      <a href="Twitter.com/TheRealZellyZel"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
      <div class="footer-socials"></div>
    <audio src="audioplayer/audio/letmeknow.mp3" controls>
      Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </audio>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qMdfC/624/)